# Ajax anchor Link trigger not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, html2canvas

I am using `html2canvas javascript` to convert html `div` to `image` file. All script are working good and it converts html div to image properly.

But when I am adding response(anchor link) to `href` and triggering it using ajax it is not triggering anchor link.

Here is my code,

**Html code:**

```
<div id="mainDiv">

<h1>Heading H1</h1>
<p>Download Image using ajax and php</p>

</div>

<div>
<a id="download">Download Image</a><br/>
<a id="download-image" href="" download>Download</a>
</div>
```

**Ajax code**

```
<script>

    $('#download').on('click', function () {
html2canvas([document.getElementById('mainDiv')], {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var imgdata = imagedata.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        //ajax call to save image inside folder
        $.ajax({
            url: 'save_image.php',
            data: {
                   imgdata:imgdata
                   },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {   
               $('#download-image').attr('href', response).trigger('click');
               //$('#downlaod-image').trigger('click');
            }
        });
    }
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the link will actually reload your page. It will still execute *html2canvas()*, but the response from the Ajax call will never be processed, as by that time the page has already been reloaded.

So cancel the default hyperlink action by adding a `return false` just before the end of the click handler (after the call to *html2canvas*).

Comment: Still i am faceing a same error. its not reponding to trigger funcation.

Comment: Does the second `a` element get the `href` filled in?

Comment: Yes, second anchor link's href filled by ajax.

Comment: What if you replace `.trigger('click');` with `.get(0).click();`?